# How to make content of port 8080 available to port 80

Tags: linux, port, streaming, webcam

I have a web page on port 80 to control a rover and I am running mjpg streamer on port 8080 to stream webcam output. I want to be able to see the stream on the web page of port 80. I have already set the default folder of web server of both ports (80 and 8080) to /mnt/sda1/arduino/www/test. I have moved all files of mjpg streamer to this folder but I am not able to see the stream on port 80 with http"//ip_address/sd/test/stream.html (sd is symlink of /mnt/sda1). It seems the mjpg stream is mapped to port 8080 only. Is there any way I can achieve this or by some other means.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? How will you control the rover if you are streaming to port 80?

Comment: what's a rover?

Comment: @barlop I guess it's a small remote control robot (with a camera) like the Mars Rover.

Comment: It requires some work. This site, https://wiki.videolan.org/Simple_Stream_VLC_to_Website/ tells you how to do it with VLC. You may try this, then come back when you are stuck.